# Como hacer que un Input escuche la resta de dos Inputs con Formularios Reactivos

Tags: javascript, html5, angular, typescript, angular9

Tengo tres input Precio de venta, Precio de compra y Ganancia, lo que quiero es que al escribir en los campos precio de compra o precio de venta el input ganancia capture la resta de los dos campos anteriores. Con formularios template usaria [ngModel], como haria esto en formularios reactivos?

```js
private crearFormulario()
  {
    this.forma=this.fb.group(
      {
        cod_barras:["",[Validators.required]],
        cod_producto:["",[Validators.required]],
        nombre_prod:["",[Validators.required]],
        precio_compra:["",[Validators.required]],
        precio_venta:["",[Validators.required]],
        ganancia:["",[Validators.required]],
        stock:["",[Validators.required]],
        estado:["",[Validators.required]]
      }
    );
  }
```

```html
<div class="col-12 form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1" >Precio de venta</label>
            <input type="number"
             class="form-control" 
             step="0.01"
             formControlName="precio_venta"
             >
          </div>
          <div class=" col-12 form-group ">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1 ">Precio de compra</label>
            <input type="number" 
            class="form-control"
            formControlName="precio_compra"
            >
          </div>
          <div class=" col-12 form-group ">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1 ">Ganancia</label>
            <input type="number"
             class="form-control"
              value="3" 
              readonly
              formControlName="ganancia"
              >
          </div>
```

intente lo siguiente pero me lanza un error

```js
OnValueChanges()
  {
    this.forma.valueChanges.subscribe(res=>
      {
        let ganancia=this.forma.get("precio_venta").value-this.forma.get("precio_compra").value
        this.forma.get("ganancia").setValue(ganancia)
      })
  }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema se debe que al setear un valor con **SetValue** en un campo de tu formulario, se emiten eventos y tienes un bucle infinito.

Para ello la solución es establecer que no se emita eventos, con el parametro **"emitEvent: false"**.

```
onValueChanges() {
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(res => {
      const precioCompra = this.form.get('precio_compra').value;
      const precioVenta = this.form.get('precio_venta').value;
      const ganancia = precioVenta - precioCompra;
      this.form.get('ganancia').setValue(ganancia, { emitEvent: false });
    });
  }
```

emitEvent: Cuando es verdadero o no se proporciona (el valor predeterminado), tanto los observables statusChanges como los valueChanges observables emiten eventos con el último estado y cuando se actualiza el valor de un control. Cuando es **falso**, no se emiten eventos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono!!!